# appending the outputs of an array method into another array

Tags: ruby

```
array3 =['Maths', 'Programming', 'Physics'], ['Maths', 'Intro to comp. science', 'Programming'], ['English', 'Intro to comp. science', 'Physics']
course = 'Programming'    
index = []
array3.find_index do |i|
  if array3.include?(course) == true
  index << i
  end
end
```

i created an array (array3) that contains the respective elements and i want to add the elements of array3 which hold the condition true but after executing the code i get a blank array like "[[], [], []]"
how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Tip: In Ruby `x == true` is almost always better written as `x`.

Comment: Hint: This is really just `index`. The `find_index` name is misleading. Additionally the argument to the [`index`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/array#method-i-index) block is not `i` as in index, but the value. It *returns* the index.

Comment: Do you want to add the elements, or the index of the elements?

Comment: Defining `array3` like that is problematic for two reasons. 1. It should be `array3 = [ [ ... ], ... ]` where it's clear that's a 3 part array. 2. The name is terrible. Call it `courses` or something meaningful.

Comment: Or as it stands maybe `course_lists` is a fitting name. This also helps the reader to understand that they're working with a nested arrays.

Comment: @tadman : The question is "elements of the array", not the index. `each` does the job.

Comment: _i want to add the elements of array3_  : Where do you want to add them to? BTW. since inside the loop, neither `array3` nor `course` is modified, the condition `array3.include?(course) == true` will either be always true or always false.

Comment: @tadman : The assignment to `array3` is correct, though a bit unusual. Think of the example `x, arr=4, 5, 8`, which sets `arr` to `[5,8]`. The OP used the _comma_ operator, which is usually used for doing para.llel assignment, for creating a single array. It saves indeed two keystrokes (the outermost square brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) does not iterate over indices. It iterates over values and returns the *first* index of the value that matches. It sounds like you want to iterate over every element, making note of *all* of the indices that match some condition.

To that end, you can use [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

```
index = []
array3.each_with_index do |courses, i|
  if courses.include?(course) == true
  index << i
  end
end
```

or you can use [`each_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-each_index) and filter the results.

```
index = array3.each_index.select { |index| array3[index].include? course }
```

or, filtering with `each_with_index`,

```
index = array3.each_with_index
        .select { |list, _| list.include? course }
        .map(&:last)
```

on Ruby 2.7 or newer, you can shorten this with [`filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map).

```
index = array3.each_with_index
              .filter_map { |obj, index| index if obj.include? course }
```

Comment: The second form is more typical Ruby and it works great.

Comment: Though I think the second form is missing the right arguments. It should be `each_with_index` and then `|list, index|` as that'd make it easier to do tests: `list.include?(course)`.

Comment: @tadman `each_index` passes only the index, not the value. You could use `each_with_index` (which does take both arguments), but then you'll have to do a `map` after the fact to get rid of the object, since OP only wants the indices. So `array3.each_with_index.select { |list, _| list.include? course }.map { |arr| arr[1] }` will work, but that seems messier to me than the `each_index` version.

Comment: A good point. I just don't like running things like `a[n]` if that was already resolved earlier, and `map(&:last)` isn't the worst. All a matter of preference, really, or performance constraints.

Comment: @tadman I don't either, to be honest. And I'm surprised Ruby doesn't have a `find_all_indices` method built-in. If it did, this would become incredibly simple: `array3.find_all_indices { |list| list.include? course }`, but sadly such a method does not appear to exist.

Comment: Great thing about Ruby is if you don't like that, you can just patch it in!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It does now have `filter_map` so `array3.each_with_index.filter_map {|list,i| i if list.include? course }` but still a bit of a mouthful in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `each`

```rb
array3 =['Maths', 'Programming', 'Physics'], ['Maths', 'Intro to comp. science', 'Programming'], ['English', 'Intro to comp. science', 'Physics']
course = 'Programming'    
index = []
array3.each do |i|
    if i.include?(course)
        index << i
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you run this?

Comment: yes of course. In irb. And in the end `index` contains the 2 elements of the array.